# How can I change the order of the stacked bar plot in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I want to change the order of the stacked bar plot in R? I am sharing the example below and the green bar will be under the blue bar, how can I can this order? See the code below.

```
d1<-data.frame(Gene=c("DNA","DNA",
                       "RNA","RNA",
                       "XX","XX"),
           Gender=c("M","F","M","F","M","F"),
           p_value=c( 0.5, 0.1,
                      0.6,0.01,
                      0.07,0.02
           ))


p<-d1 %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=forcats::fct_reorder(Gene,p_value), y=p_value, fill=Gender)) +
  geom_col(color="black",position=position_dodge()) + 
  coord_flip() + 
  scale_fill_manual(values=c('#6495ED','#2E8B57'))+
  labs(x="Gene", y="p-value")
```

[image]

Comment: This doesn't appear as a stacked bar chart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just convert `d1$Gendered` into a factor and specify the levels in the order you want them.

```
d1$Gender <- factor(d1$Gender, levels = c("M", "F"))
```

Then, run the code to create your plot.

[image]

Comment: thank you Norris, but the color will be the same

Comment: In your `scale_fill_manual()` switch the order of the colors (or specify which gender value they go with): `scale_fill_manual(values=c("M" = '#2E8B57', "F" = '#6495ED'))`